# Getting 'SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' in node react js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am new to node and react js app developement. I am trying to fetchthrid party api to get some value and return the response in the page while running in the browser.

Below is the code in the App.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
const cors = require('cors');

const App  = () => {

  const App_ID = "myId";
  const APP_KEY = "myKey"

  useEffect( () => {
    getRecipes(); 

  }, []);


  const getRecipes = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=${App_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}', {mode:'no-cors'});
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data); 

  };


  return (
    <div className= "App">
      <h1>Hello React </h1>
      <form className= "Search form">
        <input className="search-bar" type="text"/>
        <button className="search-button" type="submit">search</button>
      </form>

    </div>


  );
};


export default App;
```

In the response or if iam debugging the application i am getting following error

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
                                                                     ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I tried to validate  in  the online tool, where error pointing in the line 26 - '/div'

Appreciate if anybody can help on this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use the create-react-app tool?

Comment: Looks like you failed to transpile the ES6 modules/JSX to browser-compatible JS before delivering the JS to the browser.

Comment: HI @YoannPicquenot and Quentin, yes i used create-react-app tool. But let me know how to fix, i am not getting where is the error actually get placed?